# Pass String to Activity

Tags: android

I am new to Android development and Java and was wondering if somebody could help me with the following:

I have created an application that runs a server thread listening on a specified port. I would like to print messages received from a connected client into a TextView in the activity.

The server thread is in a separate class. The run method in this class listens for a client connection and reads any data received into a String.

What would be the best way for me to transfer the contents of this String back to the activity so that it can update the TextView?

From my (limited) understanding, only the ui thread should update a TextView and I can't find a way to get runOnUiThread to update the TextView.

Added code as requested.

Activity code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TextView messages = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messages);

    try {
        newThread server = new newThread(this, messages);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(ChatActivity.this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
```

Run method in newThread class:

```
public void run()
{
    serv = new ServerSocket(8000);
    while(true)
    {
        cli = serv.accept();
        user = cli.getInetAddress().toString();
        BufferedReader cli_in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(cli.getInputStream()));
        OutputStreamWriter cli_out = new OutputStreamWriter(cli.getOutputStream());

        while((buf = cli_in.readLine()) != null)
        {
            // Update the messages TextView with buf 
        }

     }
}
```

To avoid making things too cluttered I have omitted what irrelevant code I can.

Basically, in the inner while loop in run() I would like to pass the "buf" String to the activity so that the messages textview can be updated with it's content.

Cheers

Comment: Can you add some of your code? This way we can help you better...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a bad idea, but how about using AsyncTask? Didn't try if this would work, but it just might, since onProgressUpdate has access to UI thread.

```
private TextView messages;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    messages = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messages);

    ReceiveTask receive = new ReceiveTask();
    receive.execute(100)
    }
private void updateTextView(String text)
    {
            messages.setText(text);
    }
    private class ReceiveTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, String, Long> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    protected Long doInBackground(Integer... urls) {
        newThread nt = new newThread();
        while(true)
        {
            publishProgress(run());
        }
        return (long)0;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... value) {
        updateTextView(value[0]); //method in Activity class, to update TextView
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {

        }
    }
```

Basically `publishProgress` will send data to `onProgressUpdate`, which will then send data to method (updateTextView) in main class and update TextView.

Usually it helps if you tell people you're working on a chat. Also, run() will need to be modified, to return string back, and remove while(true) loop from it. This is NOT the best idea, I suggest you go through a few tutorials on how to make an android chat first.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried implementing this but I cannot see how to pass a string to publishProgress. Am I missing something?

Comment: Updated. I hope it'll help, although I'm not sure if this is a good practice.